# Stack VS Heap with Classes

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

Say you have a simple class with some storage data structure (list, vector, queue, etc)

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    std::list<OtherClass*> m_myList;
};
```

Now let's say we allocate this class on the heap.

```
MyClass* pClass = new MyClass();
```

Now when we add more items to this list, are they on the heap or on the stack?
Example:

```
OtherClass* pOtherClass = new OtherClass();
pClass->m_myList.push_front(pOtherClass);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is C++, not Java or C#. You are most probably using `new` too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard collection classes use an `Allocator` class to allocate memory for the items being stored. The default allocator will allocate the data on the free store. You can provide your own if you want to, and I suppose if you wanted to badly enough you could have it allocate space on the stack, but you'd have to do a fair amount of extra work to make that happen.

Note that you do *not* have to allocate the object itself on the free store to make that happen either. In fact, your `MyClass *pClass = new MyClass();` is usually a poor idea. You normally just want to use `MyClass Class;` and be done with it. That will allocate space for the collection object itself (normally quite small) on the stack, but space for what it stores will still normally come from the free store (again, via the allocator). Among other things, this helps automate memory management -- when the collection object goes out of scope, it'll be destroyed. Its destructor will the destroy the objects it contains and release the memory (all automatically).

Comment: Thanks Jerry. That class was just trivial to get the example across, my real class has a lot of other member data so it would be necessary to use new right?

Comment: @user1229962: Maybe. On the other hand, if it has enough direct members for storing it on the stack to cause a problem, it may already have a design problem anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`std::list` stores to elements on the heap so it doesn't matter where your class is.

Comment: Am I being inefficient or causing a memory leak by allocating the element myself before inserting it into the list?

Comment: can be both or neither. also you need a good reason to think about efficiency at all.. cannot answer this without knowing a lot more. learn about new/free/shared pointers, why and when you need them.. a simple rule for now: only allocate on heap if it's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The default allocator for the standard template classes allocate on the heap, no matter what.
So, they would be on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

The simple rule: If you're allocating new `OtherClass` objects with `new`, then they are on the heap. `new` *only* allocates memory from the heap. (Exception: If you use a custom allocator, which is an advanced C++ feature, they can be in whatever memory area of your choosing.)

Your `m_myList` is an instance of `std::list`, which happens to also store its internal information on the heap (but that is an implementation detail and you usually don't need to worry about it).